Managing state in custom dropdown component using flatlist
I'm building a React Native app with a custom dropdown component where one element can be expanded at a time. The component uses a FlatList to display a list of items, and each item can be expanded to show more details when pressed. I'm managing the expanded state using useState, but when I press on one of the Pressable elements, all items except the one I selected are expanded.
Here's the code for my CustomDropdown component:
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Pressable } from "react-native";
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default function CustomDropdown(props: any) {
    const { channels, friends, groups, services, setChannels, setFriends, setGroups, setServices } = props

    const [ isExpanded , setIsExpanded] = useState(null)

    const toggleState = (key) => {            
        switch (key.toLowerCase()) {
          case 'channels':
            setChannels((prev: any)=>!prev)
            setIsExpanded(channels)
            break;
          case 'friends':
            setFriends((prev: any)=>!prev)
            setIsExpanded(friends)
            break
          case 'groups':
            setGroups((prev: any)=>!prev)
            setIsExpanded(groups)
            break
          case 'services':
            setServices((prev: any)=>!prev)
            setIsExpanded(services)
            break
          default:
            break;
        }
      }

    return( 
        <View style={styles.dropDown}>
              <FlatList 
                  data={[
                  {key: 'Channels', state: channels, value: 'channel'},
                  {key: 'Friends', state: friends, value: 'friend'},
                  {key: 'Groups', state: groups, value: 'group',},
                  {key: 'Services', state: services,  value: 'service'},
                  ]}
                  renderItem={({item}) => 
                  <View>
                    <Pressable onPress={() => toggleState(item.key)} style={styles.flatList}>
                      <Text style={styles.flatListItem}>{item.key}</Text>
                      <FontAwesome size={20} name={ item.state ? "caret-down" :"caret-left"} style={{color: '#626262'}} />
                  </Pressable>
                  {
                    isExpanded == item.state ?
                    <View>
                      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                    </View>
                    : null
                  }
                  </View>
                }
                />
            </View>
    )
}


I suspect the issue might be with how I'm managing the isExpanded state. How can I modify my code so that only the selected item is expanded, and the others are collapsed?
Edit:
Here is a screenshot of my issue. As you can see, when Channel is selected the arrow icon is pointing down however the contents of the other components are being shown instead!

Seems like a lot of logic here for toggling. Why don’t you have your onpress just set expanded to the key?

@johnhaup for the purpose of my app, i need one element to be expanded at a time and i wouldn't be able to do that if i did as you suggested unfortunately

I eventually figured out how to get one element to toggle at a time. In my FlatList I just set isExpanded == item.value in the rather than isExpanded == item.state. Also in my toggleState function, I used setExpanded() to check the current value of isExpanded before setting it either to false or the value of the switch/case statement.
If there are any better ways to achieve this functionality I would still like to hear and improve on the logic.


export default function CustomHomeDropdown(props: any) {
    const { channels, friends, groups, services, setChannels, setFriends, setGroups, setServices } = props

    const [ isExpanded , setIsExpanded] = useState(false)

    const toggleState = (key: string) => {
      switch (key.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'channels':
            setChannels((prev: any) => !prev);
            setIsExpanded(isExpanded === 'channels' ? false : 'channels');
            break;
        case 'friends':
            setFriends((prev: any) => !prev);
            setIsExpanded(isExpanded === 'friends' ? false : 'friends');
            break;
        case 'groups':
            setGroups((prev: any) => !prev);
            setIsExpanded(isExpanded === 'groups' ? false : 'groups');
            break;
        case 'services':
            setServices((prev: any) => !prev);
            setIsExpanded(isExpanded === 'services' ? false : 'services');
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
      }

    return( 
        <View style={styles.dropDown}>
              <FlatList 
                  data={[
                  {key: 'Channels', state: channels, value: 'channels'},
                  {key: 'Friends', state: friends, value: 'friends'},
                  {key: 'Groups', state: groups, value: 'groups',},
                  {key: 'Services', state: services,  value: 'services'},
                  ]}
                  renderItem={({item}) => 
                  <View>
                    <Pressable onPress={() => toggleState(item.key)} style={styles.flatList}>
                      <Text style={styles.flatListItem}>{item.key}</Text>
                      <FontAwesome size={20} name={ item.state ? "caret-down" :"caret-left"} style={{color: '#626262'}} />
                  </Pressable>
                  {
                    isExpanded == item.value ?
                    <View style={styles.dropDownItem}>
                      <Text>{item.value}</Text>
                    </View>
                    : null
                  }
                  </View>
                }
                />
            </View>
    )
}



